# OpenShift mysql No Route to Host

Tags: mysql, openshift

I am new to openshift but last month I deployed a project on open shift it was working fine but now I cannot connect my phpmyadmin pod with MySQL It keeps giving me error no route to host.

this is my MySQL service yaml

`apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    template.openshift.io/expose-uri: 'mysql://{.spec.clusterIP}:{.spec.ports[?(.name=="mysql")].port}'
  creationTimestamp: '2018-04-26T07:55:22Z'
  labels:
    app: mysql-persistent
    template: mysql-persistent-template
  name: mysql
  namespace: qrattendfirst
  resourceVersion: '2207628942'
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/qrattendfirst/services/mysql
  uid: 2bb4db5e-4927-11e8-a6d6-0ab8769191d3
spec:
  clusterIP: 172.30.125.169
  ports:
    - name: mysql
      port: 3306
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 3306
  selector:
    name: mysql
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}`

this is my settings in config.inc.php of my phpmyadmin

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

full repo is at GitHub.com/Srikantkarnani/phpmyadmin

this is the error I keep on getting and also nothing changes in MySQL logs.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6PIa.png)

Comment: May be some issues with us-west-2. Also monitor discussion at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openshift/ZehNkCOK6q8